# How to split a string by value with tail in python

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to parse a DNS query in python. The message containing two queries can look like this:

```
07example03org00TTCC13stackoverflow03com00TTCC
```

The first part contain a requested domain name, where before each part of the domain name is the number of characters (bytes) that the part have. At the end is *always* a null byte. T and C stands for type and class, they have a fixed length.
I want to split a string, which contain these messages, by the null byte. I can do `data.split('\x00')`, but this cut off the rest of the query.

```
['07example03org00', 'TTCC13stackoverflow03com00', 'TTCC']
```

I need this

```
['07example03org00TTCC', '13stackoverflow03com00TTCC']
```

but I can use only the `00` part of the query, not `TTCC`.

**How can I split a string by value and add the next 4 bytes to the previous splitted part?**

---

**Edit:** As Padraic Cunningham pointed me in the comments, I don't need that zeros in the result.

Comment: Does the string always contain 00 before the null bytes?

Comment: There's always a null byte (in the example above I used "00", but in real it's \x00), because it's count of the length of root (which is always zero).
From RFC1035: _The domain name terminates with the zero length octet for the null label of the root._

Comment: why do you want `00` in the output then?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't need them. I was focused on the parts as single queries and I didn't realize that I don't need that zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example (replace the delimiter appropriately - `(?:\x00)` instead of `(?:00)`), you can use:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '07example03org00TTCC13stackoverflow03com00TTCC'
>>> re.findall('(.*?(?:00).{4})', s)
['07example03org00TTCC', '13stackoverflow03com00TTCC']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "07example03org\x00TTCC13stackoverflow03com\x00TTCC"

import re


r1 = re.compile("\x00(.{4})")
print(r1.sub(r"\1 ",s, 1).replace("\x00","",1).split()))
['07example03orgTTCC', '13stackoverflow03comTTCC']
```

This  removes the null bytes.

Comment: Interesting how we've got two completely different `re` approaches :0 - Just noticed the 50k - congrats :)

Comment: @JonClements, cheers, I was looking at findall then I thought the null bytes would have to be removed anyway so not really sure what is the next approach, I see you are close to 60k ;)

Answer (score 0):

in pure python, following your exemple :

```
>>>l=('****'+s).split('\x00')
>>>print([x[4:]+y[:4] for x,y in (l[:-1],l[1:])])
['07example03org00TTCC', '13stackoverflow03com00TTCC']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional second parameter do "split" in  which you can denote the maximum number of pieces to split (the separator is ignored in the remainder) -

```
>>> a = "07example03org\x00TTCC13stackoverflow03com\x00TTCC"
>>> a
'07example03org\x00TTCC13stackoverflow03com\x00TTCC'
>>> a.split("\x00", 1)
['07example03org', 'TTCC13stackoverflow03com\x00TTCC']
>>>
```

Otherwise, if you need to remove the "\x00" part, you migh just rejoin the parts you want:

```
>>> a = "07example03org\x00TTCC13stackoverflow03com\x00TTCC"
>>> b = a.split("\x00")
>>> b
['07example03org', 'TTCC13stackoverflow03com', 'TTCC']
>>> c = "".join(b[1:])
>>> c
'TTCC13stackoverflow03comTTCC'
>>> b[0]
'07example03org'
```

Comment: The OP wants TTCC on the first substring also

Comment: ah - sorry - this answer is useless them ,and teh proepr approach is using regexps indeed. (or create a short code using a state machine in pure Python)